# i'm used to have the IDE to create the event signature for me under vb.net, how to do it with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

for the past >8 years i was doing `VB` / `VB.Net` work

now I'm jumping into `C#` world, so far it's very easy

only thing that I find difficult is the fact that the signature of every events on object are not automatically created for me.

I'm used to select the object name in the left dropdown in the code view and then the event that I want in the right dropdown.

is there something similar to that in `C#`? if yes where can i find it, I really wish I don't have to write them by hand...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - are you trying to attach event handlers when in the design view, or within code?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, in the IDE while you view code, under vb.net at the top you have 2 dropdown, left side is list of object, right side list of "function" or event available for that object. In Vb.net you have all of them listed even if it's not written yet.

Comment: When you say "while you view code" - what exactly are you looking at? Because in another comment you're talking about `<asp:Repeater ...>` which clearly isn't the plain C#, but ASP.NET code of some description, potentially in the designer.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I realize that I mixed 2 things in my question, I will try to re-word  a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is:
Type the event name followed by += followed by a space and then hit tab twice.
Example:

```
someControl.Click += <hit tab twice>
```

this will create the event handler method stub for you.

Comment: how would I do that in this case: <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="checkList" OnItemDataBound="OnItemDataBound_checkList">

Comment: I just added the asp.net tag, sorry

Comment: In that case, it should be possible to right click on `OnItemDataBound_checkList` and select something like `Navigate to event handler`.

Comment: I don't see that in the menu, I'm using vs2010

Comment: if I start doing += at the init level of the object, do I have to remove it manually to dispose it or .net will do it by itself?

Answer (score 1):

The closest in C# is tab completion. While adding an event, press tab to complete the event signature:

[image]

and another tab to create the event handler.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but we are already past this point. He needs it for ASP.NET code, see his comment to my answer...

Comment: Yep, saw the comments after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in the  design view you can select the object you want then in the properties window you can click on the events button(i think it looks like a lightning bolt). then double click in the area to the right of the event you want.